# Nested struct or inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct

```
struct A { void f(); };
struct B { int f(); };
struct C : A, B { };

int main() {
    C* pc;

    pc->A();     // statement 1
    pc->A::f();    // statement 2
    pc->B::f();    // statement 3
    pc->A::B::f();    // statement 4

return 0;
}
```

Just curious about what's the relationship between struct A, B and C. I feel like it's C inherit from A and B. But from the statement below, it seems like A and B are nested struct of C. There are only two statements that are wrong in this code, I feel like it's 1 and 4 if it's nested struct.

Comment: This won't compile as B is defined twice.

Comment: Why don't you try compiling this code?

Comment: Sorry, there was some error for the code. Modified it already. I try to compile it, but turns out all the statement are wrong.

Comment: It's should be inheritance, just find the answer.

Comment: "all the statements are wrong" ?

Comment: @TiechengSu Obviously it is inheritance, that is the definition of `:` in the struct declaration. And no, only two statements are wrong. Two of them are valid, but of course your code is missing the implementations of `A::f` and `B::f`. It is also easy to see which statements are likely wrong. Is this homework or a test question? Why do you think the statements indicate this to be a nested struct relationship?

Comment: @Eichhörnchen Thank you so much! It is a test question. Now I know we can access base class function through `pc->A::f()`

Comment: Its not compiling because f() is not defined and statements 1 and 4 are incorrect. After defining f() in A and B, and removing statements 1 and 4, the program will compile. pc would also have to be initialized with a new instance of class C in order to prevent a core dump at run-time.